# Почему кириллица превращается в непонятные символы

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, кириллица

Когда я пишу данные в форму икрилицей в php хранит данные как непонятные символы (нп. Ð”Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ð»Ð)

Форма

```
        <form action="scripts/settings.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <button type="submit" name="change_name"></button>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
require "db.php";
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$data = $_POST;
if(isset($data['change_name'])) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE id='{$_SESSION['logged_user']->id}'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully"; 
} else {
    echo "Error updating record";
}
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Я пробовал много способов, но ни один не помог

Comment: Убедитесь что БД была создана в кодировке utf-8

Comment: Попробуйте text/plain заменить на text/html

Comment: Ничего не помагает

Comment: Команда "show create table users" покажет, какая кодировка используется в таблице.